# I want to remove Mailchimp checkbox value which is in Contact Form DB data, it combine with Contact Form 7 data?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Contact Form 7, MailChimp for WP and Contact Form DB plugin currently in my web site.

I have three forms in my web site: contact form and volunteer form. When user fills data and sends message it will send me mail and using Contact Form DB. It will save and display at admin site,but problem is that when I select contact form it will add MailChimp checkbox data also with it which I don't want to see.

How to remove the form plugin? I don't know much about coding.

Here is image:

[image: mailchimp report]

Comment: Close it I found Solution myself,its solved now

Comment: why don't you write your solution here as an answer and accept it as a correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Answer myshelf I just need to apply one delete query in the end of procedure of plugin's file "CF7DBPlugin.php":

```
$wpdb->delete( 'wp_cf7dbplugin_submits
', array( 'field_name' => mc4wp_checkbox ) );
$wpdb->query( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
                DELETE FROM  wp_cf7dbplugin_submits
         WHERE field_name = %s
        ",
            'mc4wp_checkbox' 
        )
);
```